# Как передать шаблон строки в функцию

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код:

```
function func(name, str) {
    var newStr = '`' + str + '`';
    return newStr;
}
var firstName = 'Mark';
var str = 'hi ${name}';
var f = func.bind(null, firstName);
console.log(f(str));
```

Вывод сейчас:

> hi ${name}

Как нужно:

> hi Mark

Как правильно передавать шаблонные строки в функции?

Comment: нужно использовать `\`` (где буква ё), а не `'`  ........`var str = \`hi ${name}\`;` .......хотя в твоем случае ты пытаешься сделать что-то совсем странное

Comment: В таком случае получаю, что переменная name не определена.
Смысл в том, чтобы использовать шаблон строки в функции.

Comment: @Regent не, он не о том... а то, что он хочет, скорее всего нельзя сделать. во всяком случае без кривоты

Comment: @Regent Это я понимаю, но мне нужно другое. Передать в функцию имя и шаблон. И уже в функции использовать это имя в шаблоне. Возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а, передать "шаблон" в функцию, чтобы потом в ней его вызывать для переданного значения...

Comment: @Regent да.....

Comment: @MarkL7 для этого придётся использовать какой-нибудь (имеющийся или самописный) шаблонизатор, который будет парсить строку и подставлять в неё нужные значения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такого нормально сделать нельзя.

Правильно будет передавать не шаблон, а функцию, заполняющую этот шаблон:

```js
function hiTo(name) {
  return `Hi ${name}`;
}

var firstName = 'Mark';
var f = hiTo.bind(null, firstName);
console.log(f());
```

Если же это попытка локализации, то можно самому подставлять значения, а не пользоваться шаблонными строками:

```js
function hiTo(args, template) {
  return template.replace(/\$\{(\w+)\}/g, (m,n) => args[n] || m);
}

var firstName = 'Mark';
var f = hiTo.bind(null, {name: firstName});

console.log(f('Hi ${name}'));
console.log(f('Привет ${name}'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Простым таким способом, как у вас в вопросе, сделать так нельзя (или я не знаю как). Придется городить разные конструкции или костыли. Пример:

```js
var template = function(tpl, args) {
    var keys = Object.keys(args),
        fn = new Function(...keys, 
          'return `' + tpl.replace(/`/g, '\\`') + '`');
    return fn(...keys.map(x => args[x]));
};


function test() {
    var myTpl = 'Hello ${str + "!"} and ${other.toUpperCase()}';
    console.log(template(myTpl, {str: 'foo', other: 'bar'}));
}

test();
```

<sub>взято с https://stackoverflow.com/a/41118285/6104996</sub>

---

Но как по мне, так проще для шаблонов в таком случае использовать банально [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) по регулярке

Comment: _"`template(myTpl, name=firstName)`"_ - глобальные переменные? Что-то вообще не понимаю, чем этот ответ лучше eval'а...

Comment: И тоже не работает на `tpl = 'hi \\${name}'`

Comment: @Qwertiy именно поэтому считаю это всё неправильным, хоть и худо бедно работает. Как я писал - лучше сделать вырез по правильной регулярке + иметь соглашение по правильному оформлению шаблонов

Comment: @MarkL7 не спешите отмечать галкой ответ. может быть кто что еще порекомендует. ибо это всё не так просто. вообще дельный совет - использовать готовые шаблонизаторы имхо)) либо правильную регулярку для заранее обозначенного в стандарте шаблона

Comment: **Этот пример делает совершенно не то что написано!** Конструкция `name=firstName` создает глобальную переменную `name`, которая и используется шаблоном. А `...rest` можно вовсе убрать из кода - он ни на что не влияет...

Comment: @Qwertiy ^^ вы можете перевести этот комментарий на буржуйский? А то они, кажется, там ни о чем не догадываются...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я ж в первом же своём комментарии написал про глобальную переменную.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а, понял. Написал там.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, автор поправил английский ответ :)

Comment: @Qwertiy тоже чтоль поправить)) копипаст же)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да, так лучше. Хотя зачем удалять все `\``, я не понял.

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ - передавать функцию вместо строки:

```js
var strf = name => `Hi, ${name}!`;
func("Mark", strf);

function func(name, strf) {
    console.log(strf(name));
}
```

В более сложных случаях вам потребуется `new Function` (но следите чтобы туда не попадали недоверенные строки!):

```js
var str = 'Hi, ${name}!';
var strf = compile(str);
func("Mark", strf);

function func(name, strf) {
    console.log(strf(name));
}

function compile(str) {
    return new Function("name", "return `" + str + "`");
}
```

Если даже имена переменных неизвестны заранее - придется воспользоваться устаревшей конструкцией `with`:

```js
var str = 'Hi, ${name}!';
var strf = compile(str);
func({ name: "Mark" }, strf);

function func(data, strf) {
    console.log(strf(data));
}

function compile(str) {
    return new Function("$data", "with ($data) return `" + str + "`");
}
```

Но лучше все же до такого не доводить и остановиться на первом варианте.

Comment: `new Function(...keys,` выглядит лучше, чем `with` и работает в строгом режиме.

Comment: @Qwertiy какой такой строгий режим внутри `new Function`? :-)

Comment: @Qwertiy что же до `...keys` - то обратите внимание что я разделяю компиляцию шаблона и его использование. При таком подходе этот самый список keys придется составлять вручную, что еще сильнее все усложнит.

Comment: Хм.. Да, действительно, место не то...

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать eval

```js
function func(name, str) {
    var a = '`'+str+'`';
    var newStr = eval(a);
    return newStr;
}

var firstName = 'Mark';
var str = 'hi ${name}';
var f = func.bind(null, firstName);
console.log(f(str));
```

Но, как выяснилось, не нужно. Во-первых, не безопасно. Во-вторых, такой вариант не работает с обратными слешами в шаблоне. Они не экраниру.тся и шаблон все равно ломается в eval.

Comment: А почему код из этого ответа - это плохо?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Решение выглядит довольно простым.
Почему минусанули это решение тоже интересно. Предположу, что из-за вопроса безопасности использования eval.

Comment: @MarkL7, во-первых, безопасность, во-вторых, не работает, например, на `str = 'hi \\${name}'`. Хотя минус не мой.

Comment: Попробуй ``eval('`'+JSON.stringify(s)+'`')`` - не пойму, это лучше будет, или наоборот в других случаях разломается...